# Android: Simplest Internet connection dialog with Retry/Cancel

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am stuck in implementing a dialog which checks for internet connectivity as soon as the app is opened (i.e. in onCreate()). However, I moved the dialog code to a different class to keep the MainActivity clean.

I need to check for connectivity everytime the user clicks retry, show the dialog again if internet is not present else call the onRefresh() method present in the MainActivity class.

The code looks something like this:

```
public static boolean showNoConnectionDialog(final Context c) {


    if(checkConnectivity(c))
    {
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
    AlertDialog.Builder b =new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    b.setTitle("No Connection");
    b.setMessage("Cannot connect to the internet!");
    b.setPositiveButton("Retry", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(!checkConnectivity(c))
            showNoConnectionDialog(c);
            else
            {
            result = true;

            }
    }
    });
    b.setNegativeButton("Exit", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            ((Activity)c).finish();
        }
    });
    b.create().show();
}
    return result;

}

private static Boolean checkConnectivity(Context c) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // test for internet connection
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

In the MainActivity, I tried:

```
if(DialogBoxes.showNoConnectionDialog(this)){

    onRefresh();

 }
```

However, clicking the Retry button after connecting to the internet does nothing, since the "if" part is checked only once. Using while instead of if causes the UI to stop responding.

What do I do ?

Answer (score 0):

First declare your `AlertDialog` outside of any method but inside of your class:

```
AlertDialog dialog;
```

Then inside of your positive button listener:

```
b.setPositiveButton("Retry", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(!checkConnectivity(c))
            dialog.show();
        else
        {
            result = true;
        }
}
});

dialog = b.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to put the `final AlertDialog dialog = b.create(); dialog.show();` statement ?
If I put it before the declaration of b, it has to be initialized to null, as it is final, it cannot be reinitialized.
If I put it when I call show(), the button's code is not ready for the first time.

Comment: @ShantanuPaul ahh sorry. Declare your variable as a class field so it's available inside every method. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: But the issue is not that clicking on 'Retry' should retry again but how to make the MainActivity call onRefresh() as soon a as internet is available and the user clicks Retry.